# I need to turn my table to the right in either ssrs or sql

Tags: t-sql, pivot, reporting-services

I have a table that looks like this

```
Form Name   Quoted   Issued  total
  a           5251     967    100000
  b           145      34     9779
  c           2190     545    420000
```

I need it to look like this.

```
           a       b       c
Quoted   5251      145     2190
Issued   967       34      545
Total    10000     9779    420000
```

How do I pivot the table?

Comment: Yep, you sure do... what's your question?

Comment: I tried using a matrix is ssrs. I also tried labeling the header columns (form names) myself and placing the Quoted.Value but couldn't figure out a way to get the individual value per form name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are better solutions and this is ugly but it does the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT FormName, Quoted
    FROM mytable
) data
PIVOT
(
    Max(Quoted) For FormName IN ([a], [b], [c])

) as DataPivot

UNION

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT FormName, Issued
    FROM mytable
) data
PIVOT
(
    Max(Issued) For FormName IN ([a], [b], [c])

) as DataPivot

UNION

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT FormName, Total
    FROM mytable
) data
PIVOT
(
    Max(Total) For FormName IN ([a], [b], [c])

) as DataPivot
```

I advise doing some research on [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) it can do a lot. There are lots of answers on SO if you need to dynamically create this type of query.